# Rails has_many through seems to not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I need a second set of eyes on this. When I create a Match between two players, Tournament.players returns an empty array.

**Code**

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_matches
  has_many :matches
  has_many :players, :through => :player_matches  
end

class PlayerMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :tournament
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_matches
  has_many :matches, :through => :player_matches
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :player_matches
end
```

Comment: can you add your `Match` model?

Comment: Ya, we need to see the `Match` model

Comment: You also might consider polymorphism considering both `Tournaments` and `Player`'s have many player matches

Comment: @Zippie You figured out my `Match` model. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a double `:through` relation:

`player_matches` through `matches` and `players` through `player_matches`.

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
  has_many :player_matches, :through => :matches
  has_many :players, :through => :player_matches  
end

class PlayerMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_matches
  has_many :matches, :through => :player_matches
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :player_matches
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament  
  has_many :player_matches
  has_many :players, :through => :player_matches
end
```